# Deadlock between Delete and Update

Tags: sql-server-2005, deadlock, database-deadlocks

First process:

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process8d9798">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process8d9798" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE:
    5:1:190354" waittime="3203" ownerId="53807810" transactionname="DELETE" 
    lasttranstarted="11:29:29.153" XDES="0x3dbb518" lockMode="U" 
    schedulerid="2" kpid="1792" status="suspended" spid="57" sbid="0" ecid="1" 
    priority="0" transcount="0" lastbatchstarted="2012-09-28T11:29:29.120" 
    lastbatchcompleted="11:29:29.120" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" 
    hostname="xxx" hostpid="4460" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" 
    xactid="53807810" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" 
    clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="Chooser2.dbo.DeleteUserSelections" line="15" stmtstart="360"
     stmtend="464" sqlhandle="0x030005008839117bf599a500099800000100000000000000">
   DELETE UserPlanOption
    WHERE UserID = @userId     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
    </inputbuf>
   </process>
```

Second process:

```
   <process id="processb84988" taskpriority="0" logused="1744" waitresource="PAGE:
    5:1:190487" waittime="3203" ownerId="53807415" transactionname="user_transaction" 
   lasttranstarted="11:29:13.513" XDES="0x2fc4e6e0" lockMode="IU" 
   schedulerid="4" kpid="4628" status="suspended" spid="52" sbid="0" ecid="0" 
   priority="0" transcount="2" lastbatchstarted="11:29:13.513" 
   lastbatchcompleted="11:29:13.513" 
   clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="xxx" 
   hostpid="4460" loginname="chooserpd" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" 
   xactid="53807415" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" 
   clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="Eligibility" line="149" stmtstart="10566" 
   stmtend="11604" sqlhandle="0x03000500171b4f52c1a6e200ada000000100000000000000">
UPDATE  UserPlanOption 
    SET     RateID = r.ID
    FROM    [User] u WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT JOIN Rate r ON r.FamilyTierID = u.FamilyTierID 
    WHERE   UserPlanOption.PlanOptionID NOT IN (SELECT ppo.PlanOptionID FROM 
                    @PORACPlanOptions ppo) AND
        u.ID = @userID AND u.ID = UserPlanOption.UserID AND
        r.PlanOptionID = UserPlanOption.PlanOptionID AND
        r.Criterion1 = dbo.GetPlanOptionAreaID_36()
      </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 1380915991]    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
```

Resource list:

```
  <resource-list>
   <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="190354" dbid="5" objectname="UserPlanOption" 
   id="lock1e482d80" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594060996608">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="processb84988" mode="IX"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process8d9798" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </pagelock>
   <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="190487" dbid="5" objectname="UserPlanOption" 
   id="lock25b32a80" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594060996608">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process8d9798" mode="U"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="processb84988" mode="IU" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </pagelock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

The table "UserPlanOption has a composite PK (UserId and PlanOptionId). Why does the delete cause a page lock? Can someone help me understand what is going on? What confused me for a while was that I thought the deadlock would be caused by subsequent queries from the same client, but that's not possible. These must be different clients hitting the same web page.

Actually, I guess I know the answer to the first question - deleting a range will require a page lock. But how can I get around this?

Results from index query:

```
name                type type_desc is_unique data_space_id ignore_dup_key 
------------------- ---- --------- --------- ------------- -------------- 
PK_UserPlanOption_1 1    CLUSTERED 1         1             0              


is_primary_key is_unique_constraint fill_factor is_padded is_disabled 
-------------- -------------------- ----------- --------- ----------- 
1              0                    0           0         0           

is_hypothetical allow_row_locks allow_page_locks
--------------- --------------- ----------------
0               1               1
```

Execution plans for the [update](http://heeroz.com/update.sqlplan) and the [delete](http://heeroz.com/delete.sqlplan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer updated**

### Observations

This diagram is based on XML deadlock graph:
[image]

It shows that spid52 has an IX lock on pageid=190354 (UserPlanOption table) and is requesting an IU lock on pageid=190487 (from the same UserPlanOption table). <del>I think UserPlanOption table is a heap table, meaning that it doesn't has a clusterd index. Also, this means that your PK is nonclustered.</del>  If you will run this query:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM sys.indexes i
WHERE i.object_id = OBJECT_ID('UserPlanOption')
```

you will get a list with all indices from UserPlanOption table (can you publish this list ?). In this case, because spid52 executes an UPDATE, both locks (IU and IX) shows (from my point of view) a possible **Table/Index Scan** operator in UPDATE execution plan.

But, spid57 already has an U lock on the same resource (pageid=190487). The same connection (spid57) requests another U lock on another page (pageid=190354) but this resource (page) is already locked by spid52 (IX).

Because (see [Lock compatibility matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186396%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)):

[i] existing IX and requested U locks or

[ii] existing U and requested IU locks

are not compatible you have a *nice* deadlock.

The cached plan for DELETE statement is
[image]

Notes:

- Now, a Clustered Index Scan (with Parallelism) operator forces the DBMS to scan all rows from the UserPlanOption table,
- Estimated number of rows is only 5 (estimated number of deleted rows) abd the presence of **Parallelism* operators shows that UserPlanOption table is big,
- You can see an index suggestion from SQL Server.

The cached plan for UPDATE statement is
[image]

The main problems with this plan are: Clustered Index Scan on Rate table, a Compute Scalar with an implicit conversion from `[N][VAR]CHAR` (?) to `INT` and a filter before the `JOIN` with the User table.

### Solutions

Based on these observations the solutions should be:

[ 1 ] <del>CREATE INDEX IN_UserPlanOption_UserID_PlanOptionID
ON UserPlanOption(UserID,PlanOptionID);</del>

```
-- SQL Server's suggestion
CREATE INDEX IN_UserPlanOption_UserID
ON UserPlanOption(UserID)
INCLUDE(PlanOptionID); -- optional
```

Note 1: In my option, the Clustered Index Scan on UserPlanOption table (DELETE) is the main cause of this deadlock.

Note 2: The UserPlanOption has an clustered index on `(PlanOptionID, UserID)` columns. This index helps the UPDATE statement (see Seek operator on PK_UserPlanOption_1: `WHERE ... AND u.ID = UserPlanOption.UserID AND r.PlanOptionID = UserPlanOption.PlanOptionID AND ...`) but not the DELETE statement (`WHERE UserID=@UserID`).

[ 2 ] To improve the performance of UPDATE statement you could create the sugested index:

```
-- SQL Server's suggestion
CREATE INDEX IN_Rate_FamilyTierID
ON dbo.Rate(FamilyTierID)
INCLUDE (PlanOptionID, Criterion1);
```

[ 3 ] To remove the implicit conversion you could rewrite the DELETE statement thus:

```
DECLARE @Criterion1 Criterion1_datatype? 
SET @Criterion1 = dbo.GetPlanOptionAreaID_36()

UPDATE  UserPlanOption 
    SET     RateID = r.ID
    FROM    [User] u 
        LEFT JOIN Rate r ON r.FamilyTierID = u.FamilyTierID 
    WHERE   UserPlanOption.PlanOptionID NOT IN (SELECT ppo.PlanOptionID FROM 
                    @PORACPlanOptions ppo) AND
        u.ID = @userID AND u.ID = UserPlanOption.UserID AND
        r.PlanOptionID = UserPlanOption.PlanOptionID AND
        r.Criterion1 = @Criterion1
```

The original source code (UPDATE statement) includes this filter `r.Criterion = dbo.GetPlanOptionAreaID_36(...)`. At this moment, **if** this function is called for every row from Rate table then Computer Scalar operator can be another performance problem.

Is this function a deterministic function ?

```
SELECT  r.IS_DETERMINISTIC, r.*
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES r
WHERE   r.ROUTINE_NAME='GetPlanOptionAreaID_36'
```

[ 4 ] My advice is to not use `NOLOCK` hint and/or `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED`.  This *solution* should be only the *last solution*.

Comment: What did you use to create that diagram?

Comment: Wow, thanks for taking the time to analyze this. I think I understand - the deadlock happens between the index page and the table page. However, the index is clustered and unique (it's a primary key). I added the output of your query to the post. So, your solutions 1 and 3 don't apply then. I don't want to post the execution plans (too much data), but the delete does a "Clustered Index Scan". Why would removing the UDF change things? I can't pull it out because it takes row-specific parameters that I removed from the deadlock graph for clarity. My query hints do not appear to have fixed it.

Comment: I posted the execution plans as well - see links at the bottom of my question

Comment: Wouldn't it be reasonable to assume that query hints could resolve this still? If spid67 knew from the getgo that it will lock both pages, it should wait for spid52 to complete, thus avoiding the deadlock. But how can I force this? DELETE UserPlanOption WITH (PAGLOCK, XLOCK) WHERE UserID = @userId ?

Comment: @cdonner: I updated my answer. I don't think PAGELOCK, XLOCK hints could solve the problem. spid67 uses Paralelism operator for Clustered Index Scan. This is the explation (I think) for the **strange** order of pageid locks (first U on pageid=190487 and then U lock-wait on pageid=190354) taken by DELETE statements.

Comment: The UDF is not deterministic. It appears that your suggestions for indexes solved the issue (there is no more index scan in the query plan for the delete). I need to observe things for a few more days. Purging old data also helped, I imagine. The UserPlanOption table had over 4 million rows only about half of that is needed. Either way, thanks for your stellar help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason of the deadlock is due to the fact the UserPlanOption table is accessed in different order, most probably due to the presense of an index on the FamilyTierId column.

You can read more about these kind of issues [here](http://sqlindian.com/2012/06/30/deadlocks-due-to-different-access-order/) and [here](http://sqlindian.com/2012/06/29/deadlocks-due-to-different-access-paths/)

One possible way to avoid this deadlock condition is to acquire the locks beforehand based on the UserID column before the UPdate Statement, as in

SELECT @userId  = UserId FROM UserPlanOption WITH(UPDLOCK)
    WHERE UserID = @userId

Comment: There is no index on this table other than the primary key. But I think you are on the right track with the query hint. I think I have fixed the issue.